# Como saber qual botão chamou a página?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho uma página com 3 botões que chamam a mesma página e queria saber se tem como ver qual dos 3 botões chamou a página. São botões do *Web Forms*.

O que fiz foi colocar eles pra adicionar um valor num *hidden* field pra saber na outra página quem chamou.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hdfLivroEscolhido.Value = "3";
}

protected void btnLivro1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hdfLivroEscolhido.Value = "1";
}

protected void btnLivro2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hdfLivroEscolhido.Value = "2";
}
```

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta o código envolvendo os 3 botões e o que exatamente eles fazem!

Comment: Pode ser passado como querystring, e na pagina chamada teria que pegar esse valor no pageload

Comment: Se vc quer pegar o valor em outra página, por que não guarda o valor em uma session?

Answer (score 2):

é possível utilizar o [`sender`](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=sender%20C%23) para realizar a identificação, convertendo o objeto para um botão e utilizando a propriedade .Name.

```
Button BotaoClicado = sender as Button;
        string Nome = BotaoClicado.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se entendi corretamente, você está redirecionando de uma página para outra após apertar algum dos botões, correto? Então tente o seguinte:

```
// Na página com seus botões
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("UrlDaSuaPagina?btnValue=3");
}

protected void btnLivro1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("UrlDaSuaPagina?btnValue=1");
}

protected void btnLivro2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("UrlDaSuaPagina?btnValue=2");
}

// E em sua página para qual foi redirecionado
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string botao = Request.QueryString["btnValue"];
    // apenas informativo
    minhaLabel.Text = botao;
    // sua lógica para o botão que foi apertado
}
```

Com isso você será capaz de identificar qual botão disparou o redirecionamento para sua página.